# How to set a variable sized static array to be filled with 0's

Tags: c++, arrays, size

```
int size=50000;
int arr[50000]; //valid
int arr[size]; //valid
int arr[50000]={0}; //valid
int arr[size]={0}; //error
```

I want to create an array of variable size (size) and set all elements inside that array to 0, without using a for loop, because I am testing the speed of something and need to avoid something like a for loop going through a size like 50000.

Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable length arrays.

Comment: In other words, you can't do what you are asking for in C++.

Comment: I rolled back to remove the C tag, but if you want to know about C, you should tag the question so and add the tag.

Answer (score 4):

You should use C standard function `memset` declared in header `<cstring>` in C++ or in `<string.h>` in C.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int size=50000;
int arr[size];

memset( arr, 0, size * sizeof( int ) );
```

Take into account that there is no VLA in C++ Standard. This can be only a C++ language extension of some compi;lers.

Comment: Does memset take time? or is it just as fast as int arr[50000]={0}; would be ?

Comment: @user3507072 In fact compilers internally use memset for definitions like int arr[50000]={0}; So it takes the same time as if you would define an array with the initializer list.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
std::vector<int> arr(size, 0);
```

A `vector` in C++ is a data structure that works like an array of variable size. One of its constructors, as shown above, allows you to specify its size along with a value to fill all the elements with.